# Comparing interval to continuous data

Tags: methodology, statistical-test

I have a research problem where I want to compare how well an hourly sample compares to the trends within minute by minute data of the same measure (eg. a device generates minute by minute pulse readings, but only one reading each hour is saved for viewing).

I am struggling with determining the appropriate analysis for comparison of the same measure, but on different timescales.
Beyond finding the mean pulse rate each hour and comapring this to the hourly reading, is there another method of analysis I could apply? What I really wanting to get at is the variability in the minute data compared to the hourly data.

Thank you!

Comment: Comparing the averages seems like the most productive, but it depends on what you want to know.  All you said is "how well it compares", but what does that mean?  I suppose you could take a standard deviation to see how "spiky" the per-minute data is.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts for your response. Good question regarding what I am really asking. I think clearly putting into words what I am asking is part of my struggle. I want to know the degree to the hourly data agrees or is representative of the variability within the per-minute data.

Comment: Comparing the average from 5:30 to 6:30 to the value at 6:00 seems like the best plan.  You can plot those curves.